# Viewport resize viewer

Tags: responsive-design

I have created a responsive webpage, now i need to check the pages on 3 breakpoints desktop, tablet and android.

Can anyone help for the  tools to test the page on different widths

Answer (score 0):

I usually use browser add-on, [firesizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firesizer/) for firefox, and [window resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?hl=en) for Chrome.